# Ошибка загрузки изображения

Tags: php, yii2, hosting

move_uploaded_file(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

модель

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class ImageUpload extends Model{
    public $image;

    public function uploadFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@web/') . 'uploads/' . $file->name);

    }
}
```

контроллер

```
public function actionSetImage ($id)
    {
        $model = new ImageUpload;
        if(Yii::$app->request->isPost)
        {
            $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            $model -> uploadFile($file);
        }
        return $this->render('image',['model'=>$model]);
    }
```

директория для загрузки: .../web/uploads
дамп

```
    object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#71 (5) 
{ ["name"]=> string(9) "image.png" 
["tempName"]=> string(19) "/virt/tmp/phpxZ2XOl" 
["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" 
["size"]=> int(862331) 
["error"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: Изменил уровень доступа для директорий пути с 755 -> 777 - не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен

```
$file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@app') . '/web/uploads/' . $file->name);
```